# C++ - issues with writing sorting function

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++14

I have a problem with sorting function.

I have following struct:

```
struct Object {
    int value, height;
    Object(int v, int h) {
        this->value = v;
        this->height = h;
    }
};
```

I am storing vector of this objects: `std::vector<Object> v`

And I'd like to sort it such that if the height is greater than some `i` then it should go at the  end, and if it is less or equal sort by value.

I've tried this before:

```
// some value
int i = 4;

std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [ & ](Object a, Object b) {
    if (b.height > i) {
        return false;
    }
    if (a.height > i) {
        return false;
    }

    return a.value > b.value;
});
```

But it does not seem to work..

When I have these elements:

`std::vector<Object> v = {{3, 10}, {5, 2}, {3, 2}, {2, 10}, {2, 1000000000}};` and `i = 2`

When I print values of v, after sorting I see that they appear in the exact same order

And I'd like them in the following order:
`{{5, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 10}, {2, 10}, {2, 1000000000}}`

Comment: Try to reduce your failing example to the smallest still failing one and then start debugging.

Comment: `{3, 10}` and `{2, 10}` both have `height > 4` and your comparator claims each is less than the other. I don't think the logic you described is actually what you want

Comment: Returning `false` means that you don't care about how `a` and `b` are placed relative to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want something like:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [ & ](const Object& lhs, const Object& rhs) {
    return std::make_pair(lhs.height > i, rhs.value) < std::make_pair(rhs.height > i, lhs.value);
});
```

Comment: It is not compiling with C++14

Comment: @PennyM.: Changed to be C++14 compatible (I used CTAD which is C++17).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is also a solution for your problem:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [ & ](Object a, Object b) {
    if (b.height > i) {
        // Here is change
        return true;
    }
    if (a.height > i) {
        return false;
    }

    return a.value > b.value;
});
```

Just in the first `if` instead of returning `false` return `true`

Comment: That would order every object with `height > i` before itself, which is impossible.